# Movie genre classification TF HUB

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to run the TF HUB text classification [example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/workshops/blob/master/extras/tfhub-text/movie-classification.ipynb).

I got it to run by replacing the deprecated **tf.contrib.estimator** module with **tf.compat.v1.estimator** but it doesn't seem to work well.

When running the estimator.predict function with the provided test sample:

```
raw_test = [
    "An examination of our dietary choices and the food we put in our bodies. Based on Jonathan Safran Foer's memoir.", # Documentary
    "After escaping an attack by what he claims was a 70-foot shark, Jonas Taylor must confront his fears to save those trapped in a sunken submersible.", # Action, Adventure
    "A teenager tries to survive the last week of her disastrous eighth-grade year before leaving to start high school.", # Comedy
]
```

I get this result

```
Comedy: 41.17%
Thriller: 40.76%

Thriller: 42.8%
Comedy: 42.21%

Comedy: 40.72%
Thriller: 40.69%
```

While it should be #1 Documentary #2 Action, Adventure and #3 Comedy.

I am trying to get this example working because I am working on similar project, classifying text into categories.